# Why deploying the jHipster .war application to Tomcat 8 server keeps restarting application?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, tomcat8

I've developed simple jHipster microservice and I'm trying to run it on Tomcat 8 server. It seems that tomcat is starting new instance of service after one is loaded, up and running.

I'm running web app as production app.

```
spring:
devtools:
    restart:
        enabled: false
    livereload:
        enabled: false
```

After couple instance is started server crashes.

Edit ( Please see log between one instance is deployed and another is starting up

```
2017-09-17 18:28:22.472  INFO 16950 --- [ost-startStop-1] pl.kx7.fb.pages.ApplicationWebXml        : Started ApplicationWebXml in 52.059 seconds (JVM running for 66.585)
17-Sep-2017 18:28:22.610 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/pagesmanager-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [64,878] ms
17-Sep-2017 18:28:22.611 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/pm]
2017-09-17 18:28:31.973  INFO 16950 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2017-09-17 18:28:31.973  INFO 16950 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2017-09-17 18:28:31.973  INFO 16950 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2017-09-17 18:28:31.974  INFO 16950 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2017-09-17 18:28:31.974  INFO 16950 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2017-09-17 18:28:31.974  INFO 16950 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: false
2017-09-17 18:28:31.975  INFO 16950 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2017-09-17 18:28:32.077  INFO 16950 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200

[jHipster logo]

:: JHipster đ¤  :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE ::
:: https://jhipster.github.io ::

2017-09-17 18:28:41.559  INFO 16950 --- [ost-startStop-1] pl.kx7.fb.pages.ApplicationWebXml        : The following profiles are active: prod
2017-09-17 18:28:46.559 DEBUG 16950 --- [ost-startStop-1] p.k.fb.pages.config.AsyncConfiguration   : Creating Async Task Executor
^C2017-09-17 18:28:46.722  WARN 16950 --- [       Thread-9] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1505665726722, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
```

Edit 2 
It seems that problem is appearing after I've confiugured host for my app:

```
<Host name="pm.myhost.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
                        <Alias>pm.myhost.com</Alias>
                        <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/pm" reloadable="true">
                        </Context>
        </Host>
```

Comment: Any error in log file?

Comment: Not really it seems like everything is fine application is deployed and tomcat is starting another instance. Please see an edited log.

Comment: There is no any error, neither exception during first instance start.

Comment: Could it be that embedded undertow starts up? Anyway, deploying a microservice in Tomcat seems counter intuitive, how will you scale up?

Comment: The scale is not really a problem as for now. Why not use another instance on another tomcat server? ... Regarding my problem, it seems that server is restarting app when the host is configured. Please see edit2